# QT SDK error :-1: error: File Makefile.Debug doesn't exist

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, user-interface, makefile

I have been trying to figure out this problem for a while and am at my wits end. 
The error occurs when i attempt to debug my code.
Some information you might find helpful.

QT Version- QT 5.3 64-bit for Desktop

Compilers that are auto detected

-MinGW 4.8.2 32bit

-Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 11.0(x86)
-Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 11.0(amd64)

The code-

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    ui->label->setText("It works!");
}
```

All help is appreciated my friends :)

Comment: So far the only solution that was provided was to do build-> clean all
then build -> debug all

Comment: It would help if you actually showed the exact commands you tried in the command prompt. You post an error with no context at all. I am not even sure what you are building (Qt from source or your application) or which compiler you are using given you listed more than 1 configuration.

Comment: Correct sir, I made the necessary edits.

Comment: So you are building your own application in QtCreator? Which compiler are you using? Are there any errors other than `File Makefile.Debug doesn't exist`?

Comment: Yes, if it helps this code is the culmination of the instructions given in this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HiOOWDb4YjE&list=PLD0D54219E5F2544D&index=2

Comment: That is the only error, I am confident i am using the Microsoft Visual c++ compiler 11.0, because I could not get this far without having that installed.

Comment: Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. The problem is with your compiler setup. However that is hard to help. You have a setup that I would not expect to be very widely used. I mean using QtCreator as the IDE with Visual Studio 2012 as the compiler.

Comment: What would you recommend?

Comment: I tried something and now the error is back to ":-1: error: Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options."